# Is it better to use an empty list or "list option" in F#?

Tags: f#

Is there a best practice when using potentially empty lists in domain models in F#? For example, in a todo app, a task could have 0 to N sub-tasks. Which way of modeling this is preferred?

```
type Task :
    { Name : string
      SubTasks : Task list option }
```

or

```
type Task :
    { Name : string
      SubTasks : Task list } //potentially empty
```

I am very much a beginner, but it seems to me like the business logic can work with either implementation. I would verify there are no sub-tasks by checking the option type or checking the list length for length = 0.

If we add the value of `ParentTask : Task option` to the Task record type, maybe it is better to make the SubTasks list an option as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Only use `Task list option` if there is a meaningful difference between the values `None` and `Some []`. Otherwise you're just adding a redundant possible state that will need to handled everywhere with `Option.map` etc.

It sounds like there is no difference between these two states in your domain, so you should probably just use `Task list`.

Comment: Thank you for your help! This makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

In addition, an empty list will not protect you in some cases. As in, functions like List.averageBy, List.max, etc would require a non-empty list. For those cases you might want to use
NonEmptyList option

NonEmptyList is defined here

https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpx.Collections/reference/fsharpx-collections-nonemptylist.html